# Usar % no input usando jQuery Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para permitir o símbolo de % dentro do input usando o `jQuery Mask`?

Pergunto isso, porque no mesmo campo terá caso que seja usado como formatação de moeda `1.000.000,00` ou apenas porcentagem `2.50%`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.moeda').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


Taxa: 
<input id="formaTaxas" name="formaTaxas" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="0,00" required/>
```

Comment: Mas o valor "2.50%" não é um formato monetário, então por que utilizar o maskMoney?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu errei o nome, não é maskMoney, é ` jQuery Mask`. Sabe como posso fazer para usar ou não o simbolo de %?

Comment: Se quiser realmente usar no JS (o que eu não faria), tente usar o código da porcentagem:
UNICODE. U+00025. 
HEX CODE. &#x25; 
HTML CODE. &#37; 
HTML ENTITY. &percnt; 
CSS CODE. \0025. <span>&#37;</span> content: "\0025";

Comment: @EdwardRamos qual sugestão você daria? Não precisa ser exatamente `JS`, só preciso que funcione.

Comment: Apenas deixaria do lado de fora do `input` ou mencionaria no título Ex: "Lucro Estimado em (%)". Mas se você quer usar o % dentro do `input`, tente usar algum dos códigos do comentário acima.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida segue resposta:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".moeda").mask("#.##0,00%", {
        reverse: true,
        translation: {
            "%": {
                pattern: /\%/,
                optional: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


Tax: 
<input id="formaTaxas" name="formaTaxas" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="" required/>
```